# Apache2: <Files> not applied to Rewrite substitution

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Consider this `.htaccess` in the web root.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule "^pretty/(.*)" index.php?pretty=$1

Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
<Files index.php>
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

`/pretty/sweet` is correctly rewritten to `/index.php?pretty=sweet` (with the second half disabled).

However, I get a 403 Forbidden (with 2nd half enabled)

I assumed that URL substitution is applied *first*, and then `<Files index.php>` will match the *substituted* URL, allowing access.

What am I missing or misunderstanding here, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to disallow all files? Won't it also send 403 for resources like image, js, css etc?

Comment: I want to whitelist allowed files instead of blacklisting protected files. This is a simplified example - the production version has several FilesMatch directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteRule` and `Allow/Deny` directives are from different Apache modules. Their loading order can be different from what you've in .htaccess.

I suggest you stick with `mod_rewrite` itself like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^pretty/(.*)$ index.php?pretty=$1 [L,QSA]

# block all files except some known files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:/|/index\.php|.+\.(?:js|css|jpe?g|png|gif))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sticking with one tool should make things easier.

Comment: Will do, tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: There's at least one caveat in your answer. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php` matches the full URL, and therefore only works in the web root. (I know my question specifically says that I'm doing this in the web root, but in practice, that's not actually the case.)

Comment: ok that is easy to handle, just remove `^` before `/index.php`. Check updated rule now.

Comment: Exactly. All in all, this approach works for me, so thank you very much for taking the time to explain. I did change `RewriteRule ^ - [F]` to `[R=404,L]` to completely hide inaccessible files. `[F]` gives away locations of files.

Comment: I also added `/$` to enable `/?hello` as a shorthand for `/index.php?hello`: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/|/index\.php|.+\.(js|css|etc))$ [nocase]`

Comment: Yes I updated condition with `/|` to allow landing page. `?` is not matched by `REQUEST_URI` variable anyway.